# Unable to cover overflow of input box

Tags: css

I'm trying to place an input box between two margins, but it reach to the end of the margin on the right. I tried adding in `width:100%` to see if it works, but ultimately it overflowed. Naturally, I added in `overflow:hidden` but no dice. How else do I approach and fix this issue?

HTML

```
    <div>
        <form className = "formPosition">
            <h1 className = "formTitle">Hello.</h1>
            <p className = "formDescription">Please enter your username and password</p><br/>
            <input type = "text" className = "paddingusername" placeholder = "Username"/><br/>
            <input type = "password" className = "paddingpassword" placeholder = "Password"/><br/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
input[type=text], input[type=password]
{
    overflow:hidden;
    border:none;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    outline:none;
    margin-left:80px;
    margin-right:80px;
    font-weight:lighter; 
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.paddingusername
{
    padding-top:50px;
}

.paddingpassword
{
    padding-top:40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eHQSR/48/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use `width:400px;` on that element: Its parent element has a fixed width of 560px, minus the margins left and right = 400px. That's safer for older browsers than using `calc` , which you really don't need under these circumstances.

http://jsfiddle.net/urm4u16z/

Comment: Thanks, I decided to accept your answer because of the "safer" reason.

Comment: `calc()` is pretty [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc), even IE9 recognised it. In this instance, `calc()` would give you the advantage of being able to change the width of the parent element in the future without having to remember to also change the `width` of the fields. (Edit: Note an argument against the solution provided here, just a counter-argument to the comments about `calc()`)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [`calc()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to set the `width` of the fields to be 100% *less* the total of `margin-left` & `margin-right` so, in your case, that would be:

```
width:calc(100% - 160px);
```